# When a user clicks a button on page 1 it sends data to page 2 and redirects to page 3

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

1 - User enters an information in a text field (form) in page1.php and clicks on submit button;

```
    <Form name="search_form" method="POST" action="page2.php">

    <input type="text" name="search_box" class="btn btn-default" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="search" class="btn btn-default" value="Search location">
    </form>
    <br>
```

2 - This information entered by the user in page1.php is sent to page2.php where I use it to do a query in my database and save it in a xml file.

```
<?php 

require("phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php");

$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);


$connection=mysql_connect ('localhost', $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
 die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

if (isset($_POST['search'])){
$search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_box']);
$query  = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE area= '{$search_term}' OR county = '{$search_term}' OR name = '{$search_term}' OR road = '{$search_term}' ORDER BY    petrol ASC";
}

$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
 die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

 header("Content-type: text/xml");

 while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
 $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
 $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
 $newnode->setAttribute("id",$row['id']);
 $newnode->setAttribute("name",$row['name']);
 $newnode->setAttribute("address",$row['address']);
 $newnode->setAttribute("lat",$row['lat']);
 $newnode->setAttribute("lng",$row['lng']);

}

echo $dom->saveXML();

?>
```

Everything great so far!

Now I need redirect the user to page3.php where the information entered by the user in page1.php, filtered and saved on page2.php is going to be load over a map on page3.php.

Issue: If I use header("Location: page3.php") in page2.php, the user is redirected to page3.php but the information from my query from page2.php seems not be executed/saved and don´t load on page3.php.

If I use another xml file in the code from page3.php it works.So, I conclude that my issue is in page2.php.

Page3.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">


var customIcons = {
  gas_station: {
    icon: '/icon.png'
  },
};

function load() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.349535, -6.262184),
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
  downloadUrl("page2.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");

      var convenience = markers[i].getAttribute("convenience");
      var atm = markers[i].getAttribute("atm");

    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));

     var html = "<b>Station: </b>" + name + "<br/><b>Address: </b>" + address;

      var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon
      });
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
  });
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
 }

  function doNothing() {}

</script>
```

Is there anyway that when the user clicks on submit in page1.php the information be sent to page2.php and also the user be automatically redirected to page3.php.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO! You can try query params or HTML5 storage(localStorage, sessionStorage). I'm not familiar with php  but try `header("Location: page3.php/?data=value")`.

Comment: You could send them to page 2 and then have page 2 redirect to page 3 and if you dont display anything on page 2 then the user wont see anything nor know they went to a middle page.

Comment: @Rajesh --> First of all, thank you for your reply. I am not familiar with the HTML5 storage, but I will check the documentation. Regarding the function header mentioned in php, that is the function that I am trying and it is not working.... In  my code, what would be the variable data=value?

Comment: @LaughingQuoll --> Thank you for your reply. That is what is happening... When I send the user to page2.php there is nothing to the user see there, it should only execute the query and save it in a xml file. Thus, I need redirect the user to page3.php, where the information is going to be displayed after the information be executed and save on page2.php. As you said, it is just a intermediary page.
But if I use the function header ("Location: page3.php") it just redirect the user to page3.php and don't load anything there.

Comment: Then, I am wondering if would have a function, for instance, where "action" in the input form in page1.php, could do both, send information to page2.php but also redirect the user to page3.php automatically.
If I put on the code from page2.php with the code from page3.php together, I get a error about the "Header Content-type", as my page2.php use txt/xml and my page3.php uses txt/html.

Answer (score 0):

Following is a very basic implementation of using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/Lojmd52e/).

Note: *Stackoverflow does not allow access to localStorage, so kindly test on JSFiddle.*

```js
function saveToLocalStorage() {
    var value = document.getElementById("txt").value;
    console.log(value);
    localStorage.setItem("myValue", value);
}

function getFromLocalStorage(){
 console.log(localStorage.getItem("myValue"));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt">
<button onclick="saveToLocalStorage()">Save</button>
<button onclick="getFromLocalStorage()">Get</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming that you are sending non-sensitive information...you can always send information via GET method from page 2 to page 3 and recieve the information in page 3..